# React native push-notifications OneSignal/Firebase

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Hi i want to ask a question about React native notifications. I have an app that display many youtube playlist and I want to enable push notification when a new video is added to the playlist. Is it better if I use OneSignal or Firebase for the notification ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Both Are Equal Notification funcationality here is sample project with Tutorial may be it can help.
**Firebase Push Notification** : https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notifications-in-react-native/81/
**One Signal Push Notification** : https://medium.com/differential/react-native-push-notifications-with-onesignal-9db6a7d75e1e